# Access MongoDB Array of Embedded Documents in PHP

Tags: arrays, mongodb

Hi I'm trying to reach embedded document inside this array:

```
"_id" : 0,
    "name" : "Sykes",
    "orders" : [
                {
                    "invoiceNumber" : 788,
                    "cart" : [
                            {
                                    "item" : 0,
                                    "pkgId" : 3,
                                    "qty" : 10
                            }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "invoiceNumber" : 801,
                    "cart" : [
                            {
                                    "item" : 1,
                                    "pkgId" : 1,
                                    "qty" : 8
                            }
                    ]
                }
```

I've tried this:

`db.customer.find({_id:1},{'orders.invoiceNumber':1,_id:0}).pretty()`

I need to convert this command to PHP. Any help please?

Comment: What is your expected output ?

Comment: a list of invoice numbers

Comment: Try `db.customer.distinct("orders.invoiceNumber", {_id:1})`